# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" for all of my if/else statements. What have I done wrong?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm making a basic calculator that uses `if`/`else` statements to select a sign to use in the equation. All of the `else`/`if` statements are reporting an error:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare variables

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int sol;
    bool sign;

    //prompt for num1
    cout << "Greetings! Please enter a number." << endl;
    cin >> num1;

    //prompt for num2
    cout << "Great! Now, please enter the second number." << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    //prompt for sign
    cout << "Almost there! Now, please enter the sign you wish to use in the equation." << endl;
    cin >> sign;

    //arguments
    if (sign == '+')
    {
        num1 + num2 = sol;
    }
    else if (sign == '-')
    {
        num1 - num2 = sol;
    }
    else if (sign == '*')
    {
        num1 * num2 = sol;
    }
    else if (sign == '/')
    {
        num1 / num2 = sol;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that is not a valid symbol." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //print results
    cout << "The solution is: " << sol << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num1 + num2 = sol;` -> `sol = num1 + num2;` and so on.

Comment: "lvalue" stands for Left Value - the thing you assign **to** must be on the left.

Comment: use `sol = ...` instead of `... = sol`

Comment: `sign` should be a `char` probably.

Comment: That you're required to implement _polish_ notation for calculation, doesn't mean c++ uses it.

Comment: @molbdnilo well, not exactly polish notation, but just like typing into a modern pocket calculator

Comment: You could have removed at least 95% of this code and still shown the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your assignments reversed. `=` is not a commutative operator.

They should all be of the form

```
sol = num1 op num2
```

What you are trying to do is assign the (uninitialised) value of `sol` to the unnamed temporary that results from the calculation. Happily this is a hard error with fundamental types.